# Github Jekyll Liquid object access issue in .md

Tags: github, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

So... trying to access some data I have in Github Pages. Kinda new to this.

I have some json data like so in a file called mydata.json:

```
{
  "test": {
    "item1" : {"name" : "item name", "number": "item number"},
    "item2" : {"name" : "item name", "number": "item number"}
  }
}
```

But when I try to access it like so in a .md file:

```
{% for item in site.data.mydata.test %}
- {{item['name']}}
{% endfor %}
```

It returns nothing.

```
{% for item in site.data.mydata.test %}
- {{item[1]}}
{% endfor %}
```

Also returns nothing.

I'm really trying to list out all the value for each key-value pair under each item.

I can absolutely access and print each value individually, ie:

```
{{site.data.mydata.test.item1.name}}
```

I *think* it's treating the `[]` as link wrappers because of the MD format? I have no idea how to test this theory. Am I way off base with how I'm accessing this data?

**Clarification**

Works: `site.data.mydata.test.item1.name`

Does not work: `site.data.mydata.test.item1["name"]`

Answer (score 0):

"*When iterating a hash, item[0] contains the key, and item[1] contains the value*" (see [liquid doc](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#allowed-collection-types)),

```
{% for item in site.data._mydata.test %}
  {{item | inspect}} => ["item1",{"name"=>"item name","number"=>"item number"}]
                     =>  item[0]  |------------item[1]----------------------|
{% endfor %}
```

and your loop will look like this :

```
{% for item in site.data._mydata.test %}
 - {{ item[1]["name"] }} - {{ item[1]["number"] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I went and looked at my repo, there is no preceding _ on my file name. I can access an individual property directly as stated in the OP, so the data is where I expect it. The issue is specifically anytime I try to use bracket notation to access an object.